# How do i schedule a program in python

Tags: python, windows, cron, schedule

I want a program that makes my main program run twice a week...i tried using crontab, but i couldn't make it work as i'm programming on windows (and it results difficult) and i want the program to run on windows

My main program doesn't do anything crazy, just checks an excel file and gives you some information in tkinter window

I also read about task scheduler in windows, but i want to freely edit or delete the scheduled event within the program... `any help` ?

Comment: Why don't you add your program to Windows' task scheduler?

Comment: As I said, i cant control it within the program...

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way to do that my dear friend!
First you should install a virtual machine with linux OS on your computer(use virtualbox and vmware).
You can just use linux [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)!

```
cronb -e
```

and use your favourite editor, and write this line

```
0 8 * * 3,7 python /path/to/dir/test.py
```

and your code will be executed at 08:00 on Wednesday and Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Task Scheduler API to programmatically create a scheduled task. Some example: https://ziade.org/2007/11/01/scheduling-tasks-in-windows-with-pywin32/

If you don't want to make pywin32 a dependency for this project, you may be able to get by simpler scheduling with calling schtask.exe using the subprocess library.

Answer (score 0):

Use Croniter to solve. It worked on Linux. Try it on windows.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta   #for Scheduler
import time
from croniter import croniter

# Class for Scheduling
class schedule_fun():
    def starter(self):
        nextRunTime = self.getNextCronRunTime(schedule)
        while True:
             roundedDownTime = self.roundDownTime()
             if (roundedDownTime == nextRunTime):
                 global timestamp
                 timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S")
                 #For setting variables with values
                 print ("Hi, I am Steven")
                 nextRunTime = self.getNextCronRunTime(schedule)
             elif (roundedDownTime > nextRunTime):
                 print("error")

                 # We missed an execution. Error. Re initialize.
                 nextRunTime = self.getNextCronRunTime(schedule)
             self.sleepTillTopOfNextMinute()
    # Round time down to the top of the previous minute
    def roundDownTime(self,dt=None, dateDelta=timedelta(minutes=1)):
        roundTo = dateDelta.total_seconds()
        if dt == None : dt = datetime.now()
        seconds = (dt - dt.min).seconds
        rounding = (seconds+roundTo/2) // roundTo * roundTo
        return dt + timedelta(0,rounding-seconds,-dt.microsecond)
    # Get next run time from now, based on schedule specified by cron string
    def getNextCronRunTime(self,schedule):
        return croniter(schedule, datetime.now()).get_next(datetime)
    # Sleep till the top of the next minute
    def sleepTillTopOfNextMinute(self):
        t = datetime.utcnow()
        sleeptime = 60 - (t.second + t.microsecond/1000000.0)
        time.sleep(sleeptime)

# Program starts here!!!!
if __name__ == '__main__':
    schedule =  '*/1 * * * *'
    scl = schedule_fun()
    scl.starter()
```

Answer (score -1):

[Apache airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html) will do the job

> Each DAG may or may not have a schedule, which informs how DAG Runs are created. schedule_interval is defined as a DAG arguments, and receives preferably a cron expression as a str, or a datetime.timedelta object. Alternatively, you can also use one of these cron “preset”

Comment: If you suggest to use a 3rd-party tool for something that's built into the OS already, at least make sure that it actually meets the asker's needs. Doesn't read like airflow offers a preset to run a job twice a week.

Comment: @IInspectable schedule_intervale receives datetime.timedelta object so I don't see why you could not run the job twice a week ...